# R: How to add a row that has different number of columns than the rest of the data frame?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
set <- data.frame("id"=c("one", "two","three"), "line_number"=c("1", "2", "3"), 
              "content_type"=c("paragraph", "paragraph","paragraph"), 
              "text"=c("this is a sample","first batch is:", "second batch is:"), 
              "section"=c("introduction","content","summary"))
```

So it looks like:

```
  set(view)
  id       line_number      content_type     text                   section
  one           1            paragraph       this is a sample     introduction
  two           2            paragraph       first batch is:        content
  three         3            paragraph       second batch is:       summary
```

I want to add one row on top of this data frame, which only has content in one column, now it looks like:

```
  set(view)
  id       line_number      content_type     text                   section
                                             Sample Report
  one           1            paragraph       this is a sample     introduction
  two           2            paragraph       first batch is:        content
  three         3            paragraph       second batch is:       summary
```

And R can just automatically fill in NA wherever it's needed.

I try to use rbind but it won't let me do it because numbers of columns do not match. Is there other way to do it? Maybe a loop?

Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Try `dplyr::bind_rows() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
set <- data.frame("id"=c("one", "two","three"), "line_number"=c("1", "2", "3"), 
                  "content_type"=c("paragraph", "paragraph","paragraph"), 
                  "text"=c("this is a sample","first batch is:", "second batch is:"), 
                  "section"=c("introduction","content","summary"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- data.frame(text = "Sample Report", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dplyr::bind_rows(set,x )
```

Answer (score 1):

**base R**

```
set2[setdiff(names(set),names(set2))] <- NA
rbind(set2,set)
#               text    id line_number content_type      section
# 1    Sample Report  <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
# 2 this is a sample   one           1    paragraph introduction
# 3  first batch is:   two           2    paragraph      content
# 4 second batch is: three           3    paragraph      summary
```

or for a one liner that doesn't change `set2`:

```
rbind('[<-'(set2,setdiff(names(set),names(set2)),value= NA),set)
```

**dplyr**

```
dplyr::bind_rows(set2,set)
#               text    id line_number content_type      section
# 1    Sample Report  <NA>        <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
# 2 this is a sample   one           1    paragraph introduction
# 3  first batch is:   two           2    paragraph      content
# 4 second batch is: three           3    paragraph      summary
```

**data.table**

```
data.table::rbindlist(list(set2,set),fill=TRUE)
#                text    id line_number content_type      section
# 1:    Sample Report    NA          NA           NA           NA
# 2: this is a sample   one           1    paragraph introduction
# 3:  first batch is:   two           2    paragraph      content
# 4: second batch is: three           3    paragraph      summary
```

**note on column order**

The column order is given by the first `data.frame`, that's why column `text` was moved to the left. Add `[names(set)]` to any answer to get the original order back.

**data**

```
set <- data.frame("id"=c("one", "two","three"), "line_number"=c("1", "2", "3"), 
                  "content_type"=c("paragraph", "paragraph","paragraph"), 
                  "text"=c("this is a sample","first batch is:", "second batch is:"), 
                  "section"=c("introduction","content","summary"))

set2 <- data.frame(text ="Sample Report")
```

Answer (score 1):

Other alternatives to what has already been given:

```
set <- data.frame("id"=c("one", "two","three"), "line_number"=c("1", "2", "3"), 
              "content_type"=c("paragraph", "paragraph","paragraph"), 
              "text"=c("this is a sample","first batch is:", "second batch is:"), 
              "section"=c("introduction","content","summary"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- data.frame(text = "Sample Report", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- full_join(set,x)
d1 <- d1 %>% arrange(!is.na(line_number),line_number)
```

The second step will help ensure you get your "Sample Report" in the first row.

## using base R

```
d2 <- merge(set,x,all = T)
d2 <- d2[order(d2$line_number,na.last=F),]
```

Again, the second line of code above will help ensure you get your "Sample Report" in the first row.
In both cases, the merging variable is not explicitly stated (but R by default takes the variables that is common to both datasets i.e. the "text" variable).

Comment: this is a smart hack in base R and very compact, but you need to be sure you have zero intersection between datasets, and it's probably much slower than rbind. With `dplyr` I don't see any added value compared to `bind_rows`